# HttpURLConnection - unexpected end of file

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

here's what I'm running into.

```
String link = "http://redirwebhost.eu?cbsecur=W"

URL url = new URL(link);
HttpURLConnection conn =(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
conn.setReadTimeout(5000);
urlConnection.getResponseCode();
```

and it returns 
Unexpected end of file from server. Stacktrace follows:
    java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
        at      java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)

But when

```
String link = "http://redirwebhost.eu/?cbsecur=W"
```

(/ before ?) it works OK. Do you have idea why? In curl or browsers it works OK in both versions.

Comment: Which exact version of Java are you using (result of `java -version`)?

Comment: @RealSkeptic java 1.7.0_79

Comment: urlConnection is equal to conn in your code? On java 1.8 it works fine for both urls.

Comment: @petul. Yes, urlConnection is equls to conn. Sorry, my mistake

Comment: Well, I can't reproduce your problem - having tried with 1.7.0_51, I get a 200 response code without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

It does work, checkout here - http://tpcg.io/FO0r24

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.IOException;
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        String link = "http://redirwebhost.eu?cbsecur=W";
        try {
            URL url = new URL(link);
            HttpURLConnection conn =(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(5000);
            System.out.println(conn.getResponseCode());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
}
```